# How to run a cronjob every 2 minutes on specific hour range

Tags: php, cron

I want to run **cronjob every 2 minutes** on specific hour range for example from **10am to 12am**

I am trying this:

```
*/2 10,12 * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron/index.php
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: What time it is 12am? Some think it is midnight last night, some midnight tonight and some midday.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run every two minutes from 10am to 12am, you should use `10-12` instead of `10,12` which mean at 10am and at 12am.

And if you want to run this script you should

1) Adding the php Shebang (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-shebang/)

2) Make it executable ( chmod +x index.php)

- OR -

Specify the php interpreter on run ex :

```
*/2 10-12 * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run this

```
*/2 10-24 * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron/index.php
```

The cron entry would run the job every 2 minutes from 10:00am to 12:00am.

Answer (score 1):

```
*/2 10-24 * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

To run cron from 10am to 12am

```
*/2 10-23,0 * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/cron/index.php
```

10-23 will run cron from 10am to 11pm. 0 will run cron at 12am